# Largest integer $x$ that satisfies $\dfrac{4x+19}{x+5}<\dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> Find the largest integral $x$ that satisfies $\dfrac{4x+19}{x+5}<\dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}$

I tried

$ \dfrac{4x+19}{x+5} < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}\\~\\
(4x+19)(x-3)<(4x-17)(x+5)\\~\\
x<-7 \implies x=-8 $

But the answer given in book is $x=2$

I am confused .

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths up to $12$th grade. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your proof is that you are assuming that $x+3>0$, which is not

true. To solve it, you put everything above the same denominator, keeping in mind

that $x \not =3$ and $x \not = -5$. So $\dfrac{(4x+19)(x-3)-(4x-17)(x+5)}{(x+5)(x-
3)}<0$

hence $\dfrac{4(x+7)}{(x-5)(x+3)}<0$ so $(x+5)(x-3)<0$ and $x+7>0$ or $(x+5)(x-3)>0$

and $x+7<0$. So $x \in (-\infty,-7)\cup(-5,3)$. The largest integer is $2$.

Comment: how do i determine that assuming x+3>0 is incorrect ?

Comment: You have no assumptions that tell you that $x+3>0$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can't multiply an inequality by a negative number without reversing it. You are multiplying by $(x+5)(x-3)$, so for $-5\lt x \lt 3$ the two factors have different signs, the product is negative, and you have to reverse the inequality and test that.

Comment: after reversing the sign i got $x>-7$ .

Comment: @RK OK, so every number with $-5\lt x \lt 3$ satisfies the inequality, because they are all greater than $-7$, and the largest integer in that range is ... ?

Answer (score 0):

If $x>3$, then $(x+5)(x-3) > 0$. So

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{4x+19}{x+5} < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}
   &\iff \dfrac{4x+19}{x+5}-4 < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}-4 \\
   &\iff -\dfrac{1}{x+5} < -\dfrac{5}{x-3}\\
   &\iff -(x+5)(x-3)\dfrac{1}{x+5} < -(x+5)(x-3)\dfrac{5}{x-3} \\
   &\iff 3-x < -5x-25 \\
   &\iff 4x < -28 \\
   &\iff x < -7
\end{align}

Since $x<-7$ is false if $x>3$, we conclude that $x > 3$ implies $\dfrac{4x+19}{x+5} \not < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}$

When $x=3$, $\dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}$ is undefined.

When $x=2$,

\begin{align}
   \frac{4x+19}{x+5} < \frac{4x-17}{x-3}
   &\iff 3\frac 67 < 9 \\
\end{align}

which is true.

Hence $x=2$.

### What I was thinking.

When I looked at $\dfrac{4x+19}{x+5} < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}$, I "saw" $4 + something < 4 + (something  \ else)$ So I subtracted $4$ from both sides.

\begin{align}
   \dfrac{4x+19}{x+5} < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}
   &\iff \dfrac{4x+19}{x+5}-4 < \dfrac{4x-17}{x-3}-4 \\
   &\iff -\dfrac{1}{x+5} < -\dfrac{5}{x-3}\\
\end{align}

Variables in denominators are bothersome. I could eliminate them by multiplying both sides by $(x+5)(x-3)$. But I need to be careful because multiplying both sides by a negative number would reverse the inequality.  But, I saw that, if $x>3$, then $(x+5)(x-3)$ will be positive. So I assumed $x> 3$ and the above solution occurred.